# multiple tags with same metatag value PHP

Tags: php

```
$keywords = explode(',', $this->find_metatag_value('article:tag', $page_code));
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
        {
            $keyword = trim($keyword);
            if ($keyword != '')
            {
                $result->add_tag($keyword);
            }
        }
```

This code is working but there is multiple tags
with same metatag value. I want grab all tags

Its only grab first article:tag

From:

```
<meta property="article:tag" content="som text"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="some text1"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="latest text"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="text line2"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="some textdd"/>
```

Comment: Framework? take a look at the `find_metatag_value` function first

Comment: i think, your function `find_metatag_value` return only one element instead of all. Take a look at it. Or show it to us

Comment: If I use it as..
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword, keywords1"/>
Its grab multiple

Comment: `if ($this->can_grab_tags())
  {
   $result[] = KvsGrabberSettings::DATA_FIELD_TAGS;
  }`

Comment: `public function add_tag($tag)
 {
  $this->tags[] = strtolower(trim($tag));
 }`